# How to access PostgreSQL using WPDB?

Tags: wpdb

I got a separate database using PostgreSQL and I want to access it via the WPDB class.
I tried

```
$pgdb = new wpdb('[username]','[password]','[database]','localhost');
var_dump( $pgdb->get_results('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables') );
```

but it's just showing a `null` value.

What is the proper way of accessing PostgreSQL using WPDB?

Comment: As far as I know, WordPress does not support PostgreSQL out of the box, and requires the use of things like `PG4WP` to use it as a database. Even then, I don't know for sure if you can use PG in tandem with MySQL. You might consider setting up an API for your PostgreSQL data that you can access from WP instead

Comment: PostgeSQL and MySQL are both similar, both being SQL, but the syntax is not identical, nor is database functionality. You are probably going to have to use built-in PHP functions to access the database, not WordPress one.